# Android studio strange error

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am a new android developer, and i cannot figure out why im getting this error. it makes no sense to me here are the error logs, it says its line 35 in my main activity. I also am including the activity_xml code also incase. thanks guys. ALSO I am running this on a real device for testing purposes!

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.karanvir.search.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/i">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:hint="Search here"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/s"
            android:onClick="jump"
            android:text="Go" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/t"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```css
package com.karanvir.search;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Random rn;

    AutoCompleteTextView searchBar;
    public static String urlGlobal;
    TextView con;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        searchBar=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        con=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

         rn= new Random();








    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings4) {
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);



            return true;
        } else if(id ==R.id.action_settings2){
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yahoo.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);


            return true;

        }else if (id==R.id.action_settings3){
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);


            return true;

        }else if(id==R.id.action_settings1){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                    .setTitle("About")
                    .setMessage("This app interchanges between different search engines, to help guess what your looking for. We dont not acess your location, also we do not save any information. Right now we are working on a way to make the app completely private in congnito.Email us if you want to help with this project also. Please email Dhillonapps93@gmail.com for help/inquries. We run this app with no ads, we also accept donations at runescapegold1291@hotmail.com. Yes I used to play runescape lol. Thanks for reading and enjoy");
                    return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void jump(View view){
        //intnet changing target of our code
urlGlobal=searchBar.getText().toString();
        Log.i("stuff",urlGlobal);




        int pageJump = rn.nextInt(3)+1;
        if (pageJump==1){
            //google
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);
        } else if (pageJump==2){
            //YAHOO
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yahoo.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

        } else if(pageJump==3){
            //GOOGLE
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

        }


    }


}
```

```html
07-04 21:09:00.318 758-840/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-04 21:09:00.768 4784-4784/? E/Zygote: v2
07-04 21:09:00.768 4784-4784/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
07-04 21:09:00.948 4808-4808/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.158 4815-4815/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.218 4817-4817/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.278 4819-4819/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.348 4821-4821/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.418 4830-4830/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.478 4836-4836/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.528 4839-4839/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.588 4841-4841/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.638 4843-4843/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:01.698 4848-4848/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.search-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-04 21:09:02.218 4784-4784/com.karanvir.search E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.karanvir.search, PID: 4784
                                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 187747212 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 107MB until OOM
                                                                       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
                                                                       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
                                                                       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4230)
                                                                       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:955)
                                                                       at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:112)
                                                                       at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                       at com.karanvir.search.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
07-04 21:09:02.528 758-4876/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
07-04 21:09:02.528 758-4876/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
07-04 21:09:02.528 758-4876/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
07-04 21:09:14.088 758-758/? E/VibratorService: vibratePatternMagnitude() is failed by illegal argument.
07-04 21:09:15.578 758-1529/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3036 [07-04 21:09:15.588]
07-04 21:09:19.238 3923-3950/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 7 size : 5Kb duration : 191ms lastUpdatedAfter : 26100 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 2562
```

Comment: What is strange about an OutOfMemory error? Your program uses more memry than available.

Comment: I have memory on my phone out of 5gs I have around 1 available

Comment: Your App is not the only one running on the devide. Android therefore limits what is available to each App. You need to understand, that you are developing with certain constraints. Learn to use memory wisely.

Comment: its not a memory error bro

Comment: Did you read your own log output: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 187747212 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 107MB until OOM`

Comment: What is the size of "I" in the drawable folder, that you're setting as a background? Often OOMs are caused by large images.

Comment: I don't see anything strange here. Just a regular OOM. You can't allocate so much memory at once: 187 mb

Comment: so what is my best option here guys? should I delete the images? or make more room on my phone? thanks for reading sorry im a noob

Comment: the size of I is 1270 by 700

Comment: the size of picture s is 2400x2 also

Comment: So I should re size these images right?